# Populating two types of UITableViewCell in a single UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `ViewController` called notificationsVC with two `tableView`s - notifTable and messageTable. In notifTable I have two types of `UITableViewCell`s -

[image]

As you can see there's a followed you and commented/liked your post patterns. 
Until now I have been using two UITableViewCell's like this. (reuse identifier - **cell1 and cell3**)

[image]

The first one I made a coach touch file named notification_cell.swift
and another notification2_cell.swift

**notification_cell.swift**

```
import UIKit
class notification_cell: UITableViewCell {    
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!    
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var followNotif: UILabel! 
}
```

**notification2_cell.swift**

```
import UIKit
class notification2_cell: UITableViewCell {    
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView! 
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var c_l_notif: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
}
```

I have four arrays in all -

```
var username = [String]()
var notif = [String]()
var u_id = [String]()
var p_id = [String]()
```

For eg, when I do a API call I get this

```
username-> ["Anton Griezmann", "Anonymous", "Anonymous"]
u_id-> ["2", "30", "31"]
notif-> ["followed you", "liked your post", "liked your post"]
p_id-> ["", "9", "9"]
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever there's a blank "" in p_id I know I have to initialise cell1 and otherwise cell3

This is my code for `cellForRowAtIndexpath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        var index = [Int]()

        if(tableView==self.notifTable)
        {
            for i in 0..<p_id.count {
                if p_id[indexPath.row].isEmpty {
                    index.append(i)

                //cell for followed you
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! notification_cell
                    cell.username.text = username[indexPath.row]
                    cell.followNotif.text =
                    notif[indexPath.row]
                    return cell

                }
                else {

                    //cell for commented/liked
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! notification2_cell
                    cell.username.text = username[indexPath.row]
                    cell.c_l_notif.text = notif[indexPath.row]
                    return cell

                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "hola"

            return cell

        }


}
```

What I get when I run it is this

[image]

That is the first cell is getting overwritten again. I need a way to find out which cell should be initialised at what indexPath but can't think of how. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: `String` has a function `isEmpty` to check conveniently for an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are returning wrong cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` try to return cell inside the `if - else` block, and if you want to check for `p_id[indexPath.row]` is `""` means it is empty so you can check its length or use `isEmpty` function of `String`, There is no need to go through a loop, Also.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        if(tableView==self.notifTable)
        {
            if (p_id[indexPath.row].isEmpty) {

                //cell for followed you
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! notification_cell
                cell.username.text = username[indexPath.row]
                cell.followNotif.text =
                    notif[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }
            else {

                //cell for commented/liked
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! notification2_cell
                cell.username.text = username[indexPath.row]
                cell.c_l_notif.text = notif[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }
        }
        else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "hola"

            return cell

        }            
}
```

Comment: Another way to check if your string is empty: `if p_id[indexPath.row].isEmpty`

Comment: As @vacawama suggested you can use `isEmpty` also with your if condition.